# Does not show month in Line Chart using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, charts, linechart

Here I am draw the `line chart` to show the statistical details. Here I want to show the details as `Monthly wise`. Below is the code which I tried.

```
// line chart starts
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT decease_name, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M') as dates, count(*) Consultations from prescription WHERE decease_name !='Reconsultation Need' AND date BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(),-365) AND NOW()  group by decease_name , DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M')");

$stmt3->execute();
$result3 = $stmt3->get_result();
$chart_datass = '';
$label1 = '';
$label2 = '';
?>

    datasets: [
        
<?php

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
      
            $chart_datass = "".$row['decease_name']." ";
            $label1 = "'".$row['Consultations']."', ";
            $label2 = "'".$row['dates']."' ";

?>
{
        labels: [<?php echo $label2; ?>],
        data: [<?php echo $label1; ?>],
        label: "<?php echo $chart_datass; ?>",
        borderColor: getRandomColor(),
        fill: false
      },

      <?php   } ?> 
        
    ]
```

In the `database`, the `records` shown as follows.

```
+---------------+------------+
| Decease NAME  |    Date    |
+---------------+------------+
| Diabetis      | 2021-09-15 |
| Dengue        | 2021-08-10 |
+---------------+------------+
```

But in the `line chart` it show as below.

[image]

I cant see the `month name` and it does not `group` as `month`. Could someone help me improve my code. Thanks in advance.